# Oracle Connection error after some idle time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, database-connection

I have a project in asp.net mvc that uses an Oracle database. It works nice on localhost when I make requests with short period of time, after some idle time if I make the same requests I get the error bellow (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException):

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
Linha 306:            produto = produto.Where(x => x.DESC_PRODUTO.ToUpper().Contains(palavra1));
Linha 307:            }
Linha 308: ===>        var categoria = await (from b in db2.MGL_PRODUTOS_GRUPO_SITE_VW 
Linha 309:                                   join p in produto on b.ID equals p.COMGPRO_ID
```

Linha error: 308

> [SocketException (0x274c): Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o
>   componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de
>   tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não
>   respondeu]    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +106
>   OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OraBuf OB) +85
>
> [NetworkException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Sessão de Rede: Erro de
>   leitura de pacote inesperado]
>   OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OraBuf OB) +258
>   OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.GetDataFromNetwork() +205
>   OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.Read(Boolean bIgnoreData) +52
>   OracleInternal.TTC.MarshallingEngine.UnmarshalUB1(Boolean bIgnoreData)
>   +15    OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]&
>   defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean
>   bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType
>   statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch,
>   Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
>   initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds,
>   Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller,
>   MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]&
>   rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean&
>   bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList,
>   Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired) +2908
>
> [OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Sessão de Rede: Erro de
>   leitura de pacote inesperado]
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(OracleTraceLevel
>   level, OracleTraceTag tag, Exception ex, OracleLogicalTransaction
>   oracleLogicalTransaction) +1218
>   OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]&
>   defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean
>   bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType
>   statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch,
>   Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
>   initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds,
>   Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller,
>   MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]&
>   rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean&
>   bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList,
>   Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired) +3275
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String
>   commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
>   commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl,
>   OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
>   clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]
>   scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
>   bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64&
>   internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML,
>   Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF) +14183
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean
>   requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior) +3150
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +160
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +176
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.d__c.MoveNext()
>   +249
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing
>   the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.d__c.MoveNext()
>   +334    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.d__0`1.MoveNext()
>   +1515    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +59

Comment: My guess would be that you have a firewall of some sort between the middle tier machine and the database server that is incorrectly configured to kill connections that have been idle too long.  It could also be that the network is sufficiently unstable that connections are getting dropped accidentally but that is much less likely.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Justin ! I will check it.

Comment: It could be also that you're disconnected on timeout, which can be both the .NET connection setting, and an Oracle server setting